# how can i check where the google font request is coming from?

Tags: html, css, fonts, prestashop

I recently installed a SSL certificate on my (prestashop) website.
my site won't diplay a green bar because:
Mixed Content: The page at 'website' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,300,700'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
i don't even use this font.
i checked some css files and tpl header files but i can't find where this request is coming from.

when i inspect elements in google chrome the only thing i can find is:
'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,300,700'

is there a easy way to see from wich file this request is coming from?

Comment: Try changing any `http://` to just `//` in resource links/includes. This should instruct the client to use the same protocol as the request to the website (eg http://website will load http://fonts.google..., and https:// will load https://)

Comment: Press F12 and look at you network log, it should give you more information. View the source and search it to see if you can find it there. Grep your sourcecode for the url. Ultimately it could be injected in many places but without even knowing what type of backend you're using it will be difficult for us to help.

Comment: What's the url of your website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request is being made from static-captions.css

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,300,700);

.tp-caption.roundedimage img {
    -webkit-border-radius: 300px;
    -moz-border-radius: 300px;
    border-radius: 300px;
}
```

[image]

Give it a try with this

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,300,700);

.tp-caption.roundedimage img {
    -webkit-border-radius: 300px;
    -moz-border-radius: 300px;
    border-radius: 300px;
}
```

Maybe google will rewrite the schemes embedded in that css response.

It seems like it's a prestashop module causing the issue. Is there a module named "Rev Slider" or similar.  Try removing that and see if the issue goes away.